# Website not showing in Google search results?

Tags: google-search

A website that I recently launched isn't being displayed in Google search results, despite having the site setup with Google's Webmaster Tools, and the site showing well in Bing & Yahoo searches.

http://andover-tc.gov.uk/

Any ideas?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Answer (score 2):

"*A website that I recently launched...*" is the key here. Give google some time, it has more important sites to crawl right now - it will find yours within a couple weeks.

You need to focus on getting the word out and making your site useful while you wait.

Comment: Hi @Xeoncross, the site was launched 6-8 weeks ago. Would you expect results to be showing by now?

Comment: @TomPerkins, yes. In fact, the site [is showing up in google search results](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Aandover-tc.gov.uk). It's just now showing up for whatever keywords you want. Google must not value this site much yet.

Answer (score 0):

In order for specific keywords bring your website to the front pages of Google, it is recommended to use some kind of SEO (Search Engine Optimization).

This will analyze the key words present in your site; bringing the relevant key terms to put your website on the front pages of search engines.

Here is some more info on what SEO is and how to get started:
https://ahrefs.com/blog/seo-basics/

**What is SEO?**

Search Engine Optimization (SEO) is the process of growing a website’s organic search traffic. It’s where you do things that help you show up and rank higher in a search engine’s organic results.